# Routing in Javascript (multiple files)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, js-routes

I am accessing `api.js` from `Routes.js` but I am getting an error that function `my_function_in_api` is not defined. My code is as follows, please advise where is the problem:

**Routes.js**

`var val = require('file name')`

`modules.exports = function(app){
app.get('/test_function',function(req,res){
val.my_function_in_api(req,res)})`

**api.js**

`module.exports = (function() {
return {
my_function_in_api: function(req,res) {
// do something}})`

Comment: Are your importing `my_function_in_api` from `api.js` with `var val = require('file name')` ?? if so, should not it be ``var val = require('api.js')` ?? On the other hand... is this AngularJS(1.x) or Angular (2+)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Fischer's answer, you are exporting from api.js as a function, so in Routes.js you need to actually call the default function exported from api.js:

```
val().my_function_in_api // etc
```

Full code:

```
var val = require('./api.js') //observe the "./" before the api.js

modules.exports = function(app){
app.get('/test_function',function(req,res){
val().my_function_in_api(req,res)}) // notice the parentheses after val
```

Comment: Thanks all, I did use `./` before the file name adding `()` helped

Answer (score 0):

I think you should require api.js by using
`var val = require("./api.js")` which I guess is the file name, but be sure to add `./` for requiring of files you created.

**Routes.js**

```
var val = require('./api.js') //observe the "./" before the api.js

modules.exports = function(app){
app.get('/test_function',function(req,res){
val.my_function_in_api(req,res)})
```

**api.js**

```
module.exports = (function() {
return {
my_function_in_api: function(req,res) {
// do something}})
```